# Can every even natural number n be written as $\sum^N_{i=1}2^i\cdot f(i)$, where $f(i)$ is either zero or one?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, computer-science

This seems like something that should be trivial but I am having trouble showing it.

Comment: Try googling "binary representation". That's all this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you write an integer in binary?